# Error while trying to compress pdf using ghostscript recursively via loop

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, find, ghostscript

I intend to compress a few thousand PDF files in a folder recursively.
I tried with following loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
find "/home/user/original" -type f -name *.pdf | while read -r file
do
  gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dQUIET -sOutputFile="/home/user/processed$file" "$file"
done
```

*(processed$file is used because $file brings a / at beginning & I've also tried processed/$file)*
Anyway, running the loop gives the following error:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: **** Could not open the file /home/user/processed/home/user/original/test001.pdf .
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
```

For some reason its looking for pdf in path/to/output/path/to/input. I tried changing to ./ links instead of / but to no avail.
If I run the following on its own, it outputs a compressed pdf nicely

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dQUIET -sOutputFile="/home/user/processed/output.pdf" "input.pdf"
```

Any ideas why the loop isn't working?
P.S. All directories are 777 for now to make sure there aren't any permission errors

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  Have you looked at the output of `find` directly, before piping it to `while read ...`?

Comment: Thnaks. Yes, find outputs list of pdf files nicely.

Comment: Can you use `cd /home/user/original` and `find . -type f ...` instead? That should give you paths starting with `./`, which you can use like `/home/user/processed/$file` (note extra slash).

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: I tried changing to find . -type [...] and decended to /home/user/original and ran the script. It now gives the following error: "Could not open the file /home/user/processed/./filename.pdf". Is this a permission error or is it trying to read in output folder!?

Comment: You say you "tried changing to ./ links instead of / but to no avail" -- please could you [edit the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/494425/edit) to expand on that?  Which exact part of your script did you change, and what was the resulting error message?

Comment: By that I basically did what dirkt suggested above. Whatever I do it applies after /home/user/processed/[...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing a few times, I have observed the following behaviour with Ghostscript. When you specify the output file as `/home/user/processed/home/user/original/test001.pdf`, the `gs` command expects that the path leading up to the file (`/home/user/processed/home/user/original/`) already exists. Since the folder structure from your source does not currently exist at the destination, the command throws an error and shows that it is unable to open the destination file.

To fix that, you can first recreate your folder structure with the following commands:

```
cd /home/user/original
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p -- /home/user/processed/{} \;
```

Once this is done, you can run your script to generate the PDF files. I am able to use your `gs` command to generate a PDF file, so I'm assuming that there are no further problems with it.

After the script's completion, if you suspect that there are empty directories at the destination, and want to get rid of them, use the following find command:

```
find /home/user/processed/ -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: Ah this works beautifully. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 1):

## The Problem

By default, `find` performs the `-print` action:

> ```
>  -print
> ```
>
> True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a newline.

The "full file name" means that you'll see the absolute path to each file:

```
/home/user/original/test001.pdf
/home/user/original/test002.pdf
...
/home/user/original/test999.pdf
```

So when you use

```
gs -sOutputFile="/home/user/processed$file"
```

...inside the loop, the variable `$file` contains `/home/user/original/test001.pdf`, and the whole expression expands to the two paths concatenated:

```
gs -sOutputFile="/home/user/processed/home/user/original/test001.pdf"
```

This is reflected by the error message you saw:

```
Could not open the file /home/user/processed/home/user/original/test001.pdf
```

## Using the basename

If you only want the file's basename (because all files are in the same source folder), you can tell `find` to use a different output format.

```
find "/home/user/original" -type f -name *.pdf -printf '%f\n'
```

> ```
>    -printf format
> ```
>
> True; print *format* on the standard output, interpreting `\'  escapes and `%' directives.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>         \n     Newline.
>
>         %f     File's name with any leading directories removed (only
>                  the last element).
> ```

## Using the relative name

Alternately (if the input files are in different directories), you will need to trim *some* of the directory path.  You could use eg. `cut` for that:

```
find "/home/user/original" -type f -name *.pdf | cut -d/ -f5- | while read -r file
do
    gs [...] -sOutputFile="/home/user/processed/$file" "/home/user/original/$file"
```

This removes everything up to and including the 4th `/` of the input.  However, it won't handle the creation of new output directories to match the structure of the input tree.

Comment: Ah well that does make sense but unfortunately, I want to maintain directory structure in processed folder as well. /home/user/original/foo/bar/01.pdf should go to /home/user/processed/foo/bar/01.pdf.

Comment: Also, above doesn't work as find only outputs pdfs without path so I end up getting 3kb pdf files.

Comment: FYI, this was an extremely helpful reply. It identified the root cause of the error and that really helped.